# Include javascript dojo files via Twig in Symfony 2

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, dojo, assetic

I try to achieve a simple goal: add developped dojo classes in a symfony2 html page with Twig.

I had read a lot of documentation on assetic, and i found two types of method to include assets:

The first one with the asset() twig function. And the second one with the "javascripts" tag.

The assets function is used to include files which are stored in the web/ folder whereas javascripts tag load files which are stored in the resource folder of the current bundle.

My dojo classes files are stored in the resource folder of a bundle, so i tried to load them with a javascripts tag like this:

```
{% javascripts '@MyBundle/Resources/public/js/MyClass.js' output= 'js/myBundle/MyClass.js'   %}
  <script type='text/javascript' src='{{ asset_url }}'></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

And it work, my file is successfully included, unfortunately the name is not "MyClass.js" but "MyCmass_MyClass_1.js". I have executed the assetic:dump --env=prod command but my file name still "MyCmass_MyClass_1.js"

What can I do to correct this ?

(I tried to delete the cache, relaunch my server in prod/dev, launch the assetic command with the dev env, and no change).

Comment: Just visit your site in production mode, not in development.

Answer (score 0):

Visit your site in production mode: `yoursite.com/app.php` instead of `yoursite.com/app_dev.php`, or point your webserver to correct file in web folder: `web/app.php`.